# How can I create ClickOnce application installer which will install prerequisite software packages along with my application setup

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-installer, clickonce

I am creating ClickOnce application setup by publishing it with visual studio 2013.
But the problem is my application needs silverlight to be preinstalled on client machine to make my application work.
So I want to create the installer which will automatically install silverlight with my ClickOnce application installation.

Comment: That's a good idea. And what have you done so far?

Comment: @montonero I tried to publish it from visual studio and added silverlight download link in prerequisite textbox expecting(it is silly though) that it would download the silverlight while installing my application but it does not.

Comment: Have you seen this article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/8st7th1x%28v=vs.60%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ?